# Python pyplot.hist: how to scale each bar to a sum of 1?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I currently have stacked histogram coded as follows:

```
x_multi = [np.random.randn(n) for n in [10000, 5000, 2000]]
pyplot.hist(x_multi, 10, histtype='barstacked')
```

However, I want to scale each stacked bar to a height of 1, so that y-axis now depicts percent of the bin (ie, % each stacked bar) each series-bar represents. Something like this:

[image]

However, this image is from a different example on the web using hard coded categories (as seen in the x-axis). Can this be done using pyplot.hist, automatically retaining the proper binning and x-axis?

Comment: Funny, the plot that you're showing has an example how to create this plot: [check this out!](https://python-graph-gallery.com/13-percent-stacked-barplot/)

Comment: I edited the post to indicate the difference I'm looking for. Basically, can the plot be achieved using pyplot.hist (or similar histogram function), so as to retain proper automatic binning and x-axis creation?

Comment: Now I got you ;-) See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there is not an easy solution.
The quickest way is to compute the histogram using matplotlib's `hist` function, then normalize it and then re-plot it using the bar command. I generalized this now for an arbitrary amount of stacked units. 
It also calculates the real centers of the bins, not only the edges.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
d = np.random.randn(300).reshape(3,100)

def percentage_bar_stack(data, bins=10):
    '''Creates a stacked histogram bar chart using data and a given amount of bins'''
    data_binned, edge_bins, patches = plt.hist(data.T, bins=bins, stacked=True, width=.5)
    plt.title('stacked bar chart, raw')

    real_bins = [(edge_bins[i]+edge_bins[i+1])/2 for i in range(bins)]

    data_binned = np.array(data_binned)
    data_binned /= data_binned.sum(0)

    plt.figure()
    print(data_binned)
    for i in range(len(data_binned)):
        plt.bar(real_bins, data_binned[i], bottom=data_binned[:i].sum(0), width=.5)
    plt.title('normalized to percentage')

percentage_bar_stack(d)
```

[image: Correct stacked bar chart normalized per bar]